# Можно ли здесь поставить авторское тире?

Tags: тире, сказуемые, авторская-пунктуация, подлежащее

В Сети был вопрос о возможности постановки тире в следующем предложении:

***Эмоции, ощущения — только окрашивают то**, что мы думаем, или подталкивают мысль в каком-то отношении, но мысли наши все формулируются языком.*

Автору хочется поставить тире, но правило для этого случая подобрать трудно, и он спрашивает, можно ли объяснить тире задумкой автора?

Так можно поставить там авторское тире или нет? И что делать, если тире очень хочется поставить?

Comment: ***Что** мы думаем* — разве так можно?

Comment: Артем, а если так: Быстро лечу я по рельсам чугунным, Думаю думу свою (нар.-поэт.)  :))  Я не стала править стиль, там есть еще недочеты.

Comment: ***Ну да...)***

Comment: Не поняла, что да.  Интонационное тире будем ставить? Вроде бы оно здесь совсем не на месте.

Comment: Думаю думу — думаю что, действительно. Тире мне тоже не нравится, хотя если кто-то называет эти *эмоции, ощущения,* а потом задумывается и выносит своё суждение, может, тогда оно и имеет место.

Comment: Артем, автор имеет право что-то выделить в своем тексте, в частности используя для этого интонационное тире. Но такое тире нельзя ставить в любой месте предложения.  В данном случае тире  между подлежащим и сказуемым останется только графическим знаком, на структуру и интонацию оно не повлияет. Следовательно, предложение надо перестроить, если мы хотим подчеркнуть часть фразы. Что бы вы могли для этого предложить? Вы, собственно говоря,  в ваших рассуждениях на правильном пути.

Comment: Не знаю... Подумал и ничего не приходит в голову. :(

Comment: Еще думайте, больше думайте! :)) Вопрос на 25 магров минимум (магры - это магическая валюта, почти как у нас).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну хорошо, перестроить так перестроить. =) Пусть будет так:

***Ну а что** эмоции, ощущения — **они** только окрашивают то, что мы думаем, или подталкивают мысль в каком-то отношении, но мысли наши все формулируются языком.*

Comment: Артём, опередил меня :) Я тоже хотел добавить *они*.

Comment: Забавно, Александр))

Comment: Александр, кто не успел, тот опоздал, тут уж ничего не поделаешь. :)) Я же  немного стиль поправлю: Эмоции, ощущения — они только окрашивают то, о чем мы думаем, или подталкивают мысль в каком-то отношении, но все наши мысли  формулируются языком. Ну вот, 35 у.е. ваши!

Comment: Отлично! А *ну а что* вам не понравилось?

Comment: Начало фразы зависит от предыдущего контекста, а мы не знаем его. Также здесь возможны два стиля:  ну а что (разговорный) и что касается эмоций, ощущений (книжный).